# Sousaphone repair suggestions

Tags: repair, brass, sousaphone

I've recently bought a cheap battered second (probably mode) hand sousaphone on a garage sale. It is in faily bad shape, but the valves look ok.

The instrument is made of a metallic grey alloy which shows through the cracked white paint. What could that alloy be? I need to make some repairs, and weld / solder some pieces together. What are the best options for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normally use silver solder on brass instruments. It may take a propane torch instead of a soldering iron. A lot of instruments are silver-plated brass.

Check for and seal leaks in the joints and around the valves and spit valves. They can cause resonance problems that  make it hard to hit certain notes.

Comment: Hey, nice answer. I have a friend's beater trombone, and one of the tube spacers has come unstuck. Problem is that it appears to be gold plated (or something that looks like gold). If I torch it and silver-solder braze it back together, the plating is going to come off, right? (the spacer is too heavy to use a soldering iron, I think). Is there any way to re-plate it after brazing, or is it just going to look ugly what ever happens?

Comment: It's possible to replate it after soldering it, but I don't know the details of how it's done. Local music stores that sell band instruments can usually do that.

Comment: probably a good idea to get a pro to do it, considering it's not my instrument. I might get an old beater and have a practice on that when it breaks :)